# FullCalendar find a common time among multiple resources

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

I am integrating fullCalendar in one of my ROR app. Recently I started using  `vertical_resource_view`.

I need to provide a functionality like "find a time" provided by Google Calendar in which we can select a common time among multiple users(resources) and create an event for that time interval.

But when I think currently fullCalendar don't allow to select through multiple resources. You can select a time interval for a singular resource only.

Is there a way by which I can select a time period which will be selected for multiple resources.

Here, I am attaching a ScreenShot of what functionality is currently available and what I want.

[image: FullCalendar doubt]

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately you're right. You'd have to allow the user to select on one resource using the standard functionality, then pop up a custom dialog box asking them if they want it to apply to multiple resources, and allow them to select the resources from a list. Then you can specify the multiple resources in the event object as `resourceIds: ['a', 'b'],` (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resources-and-events). Perhaps it would be worth you making a feature request to fullCalendar to add this functionality (if there isn't one pending already) - https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features

Comment: @ADyson Thanx for the information. Really Appreciated